# PowerCLI to schedule VM Hardware update?

Tags: vmware, powercli

Anyone know of a script that I can run to install vmx-09 on my servers at a scheduled time?

I have a number of servers that need to be upgraded and most can only be shut down after hours.  Since I need to get these done preferably before I come in in the morning, I'd like to schedule them around 7am.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://ict-freak.nl/2009/07/15/powercli-upgrading-vhardware-to-vsphere-part-2-vms/) script apparently uses the [UpgradeVM_Task](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.wssdk.pg.doc/PG_VM_Config.12.10.html) method to target hardware v7. I haven't tried it.

In case you're using the Windows Task Scheduler, [here](http://www.virtu-al.net/2009/07/10/running-a-powercli-scheduled-task/) are two ways to schedule a PowerCLI task.

[Update Manager](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.vsphere.upgrade.doc/GUID-81FDD2AE-6E89-490E-9376-C7523C4DEFF8.html) sounds like [another thing](http://communities.vmware.com/message/2209442) to check out.

Answer (score 2):

This will upgrade HW compatibility on next reboot:

```
$Spec = [VMware.Vim.VirtualMachineConfigSpec]@{
    ScheduledHardwareUpgradeInfo = [VMware.Vim.ScheduledHardwareUpgradeInfo]@{
        UpgradePolicy = 'always'
        VersionKey = 'vmx-10'
    }
}
$vm.ExtensionData.ReconfigVM_Task($Spec)
```